# Can't create a scroll in a limited height container in flutter web

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am using flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.6 in channel beta.
I want to create a scroll in a container which has a limited height, but it doesn't work as i want. (It works well on mobile)
[image: see image]
My code:

```
Container(
  height: 200,
  child: ListView(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.purple[600],
      ),
      Container(
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.purple[500],
      ),
      Container(
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.purple[400],
      ),
      Container(
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.purple[300],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Could you specify exactly, what is not working. The scrolling..? the widget itself is not displayer or the size restriction is not applies.?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `SingleChildScrollView` to make a widget scrollable.